# UWP C# - HTTP Webcam Live Streaming Server useing MPEG-DASH

Tags: c#, uwp, webcam, http-live-streaming, mpeg2-ts

I have implemented a UWP C# App that live streams my webcam over HTTP to a browser useing MPEG-DASH.

I have already succsessfully implemented the HTTP server and the HTML5/Javascript client.

For the MPEG-DASH live stream I use the H.264 encoding profile. As the video container, I want to use "MPEG2TS". But it throws an exception, can't use it (see code example below).

[ContainerEncodingProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.mediaproperties.containerencodingproperties) seems to support "MPEG2TS" video container.

Windows 10 and UWP Apps seems to support H.264 encoding with "MPEG2TS" container. [Supported codecs - UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/supported-codecs)

Why I can't set the Subtype property to "MPEG2TS" in the ContainerEncodingProperties object?

```cs
var mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();

var mediaEncodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.HD1080p);

var containerEncodingProperties = new ContainerEncodingProperties();
containerEncodingProperties.Subtype = "MPEG2TS";
//Throws System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'

mediaEncodingProfile.Container = containerEncodingProperties;

var stream = new MemoryStream().AsRandomAccessStream();
await mediaCapture.StartRecordToStreamAsync(mediaEncodingProfile, stream);
```

Comment: can you share us your target SDK version. It seems I can reproduce it from my side.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I use an UWP App with target and min version "Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0; Build 16299)". I tried it on Windows 10 16299.19 and Windows IoT Core 16299.15. In both cases I got the exception.

Comment: Added to Microsoft Developer Feedback. Please upvote it, if you have the same problem: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/35906611-uwp-c-set-subtype-mpeg2ts-to-containerencodin

Comment: Current workaround to live stream webcam (only video (like MJPEG), no audio) to browser: https://www.hackster.io/sascha/browser-webcam-live-stream-with-windows-iot-core-raspberry-3-1dc38b

Comment: Microsoft closed Developer Feedback, I added the bug to appropriate GitHub repository https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/2087

Comment: The reason to make a real video live stream (MPEG-DASH) from webcam in an UWP app is, that only UWP apps runable on "Windows IoT Core".

Microsoft plans to create "Windows IoT Enterprise LTSC 2021" in 2021, wich contains the best of "Windows IoT Core" and "Windows IoT Enterprise". With "Windows IoT Enterprise LTSC 2021" it should be possible to make a real video live stream with audio (MPEG-DASH) from a webcam on small devices.

Channel 9 video: Windows for IoT - A Roadmap update: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Internet-of-Things-Show/Windows-for-IoT-A-Roadmap-update